# Android Studio show the dialog "unable to create debug bridge : unable to start adb server: unable to obtain result of 'adb version'"

Tags: android, android-studio

When I open Android Studio, it shows the dialog below, and my application can't run as debug mode.

[image: Unable to create Debug Brisge. Unable to start adb server. Unable to obtain result of 'adb version']

Answer (score 24):

Find the folder of sdk->platform-tool then run the command `adb tcpip 5555`.

This should result in the following:

[image: adb tcpip 5555 result]

Now restart Android Studio and reconnect the Android Monitor:

[image: Reconnect android monitor]

Comment: In first image, `restarting in TCP mode: 5555` will be displayed only when an emulator is running, otherwise it displays `error: no connected devices`.

Answer (score 8):

1. Stop adb from terminal by calling adb kill-server repeatedly to kill all running unstances of adb.
2. Disable adb integration at android Studio by unmarking “Enable ADB Integration” (from toolbar -> Tools -> Android -> Enable ADB Integration).
3. Enable ADB Integration again by marking “Enable ADB Integration”.
4. Finally run project, so adb will be started automatically and properly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Android Studio 3.2 uses DNS to resolve "localhost" on OSX (that seems like a bad idea, Google), and in my case a bad DNS entry on the local DNS server broke things.

`nmr2:notes nathan$ hostname
nmr2
nmr2:notes nathan$ host nmr2
nmr2.mycompany.co has address 192.168.0.31
nmr2:notes nathan$ host localhost
localhost.mycompany.co has address 192.168.0.85
nmr2:notes nathan$ sudo grep -rni 192.168.0.85 /etc`

So, verify that localhost resolves to 127.0.0.1